# Having a vue variable in a tag in the template section

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a dynamic tag, but when I type it out my phpstorm says that the attribute is not allowed.

Here is the code

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card" v-for="product in products" v-if="product.product_id == null">
            <div class="card-header" :id=product.title >
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left"
                            type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#collapse-" + product.id
                            aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapse-" + product.id>
                        {{ product.title }}
                    </button>
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse-" + product.id
                    class="collapse"
                    :aria-labelledby=product.id
                    data-parent="#accordionExample"
                    v-for="childProduct in products"
                    v-if="childProduct.product_id === product.id">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ childProduct.title }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this [dynamic-props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#passing-static-or-dynamic-props)

```
id="collapse-" + product.id` 
:id="'collapse-' + product.id"`

//Similar thing on
:id=product.title
data-target="#collapse-" + product.id
aria-controls="collapse-" + product.id
:aria-labelledby=product.id
```

This `v-for="childProduct in products"` is the same loop that you're already in, maybe here a tags loop